# Upgrading Newtonsoft.Json from 10.0.3 to 11.0.1

Tags: json.net

I have just used the **NuGet Package Manager** to see what updates are available and it informed be about **10.0.3** - **11.0.1**:

[image: Newtonsoft.Json Upgrade]

I understand that a main version number change can be code breaking. How can I ascertain the issues I will have if I upgrade the package? I could not see any information.

I see similar questions but they were for version 6x.

Comment: Do the [release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases) help?

Comment: That is interesting. I am out of my depth with all this!

Comment: I did upgrade and it **seems** to function OK.